# updating pytable by selecting rows

Tags: python, pytables

Once again, I need the help from someone experienced with PyTables...

I have a PyTable (.h5 file) and I have to update its rows in a very tricky way...I explain...

The table looks more or less like this

```
Day  attempt   ok

1      1      1

1      2      0

1      3      1

2      1      1

2      2      1

2      3      1

3      1      1

3      2      1

3      3      0
```

As you can see each day has 3 attempts, and the result of the attempt can only be 0 or 1.

The main idea of this is that, if any attempt IN A DAY is failed (=0) then ALL of the attempts for that day MUST be considered failed(=0)

In that particular case the resulting PyTable, after processing would look like:

```
Day  attempt   ok

1      1      0

1      2      0 #this was 0, then all 0 for day1

1      3      0

2      1      1

2      2      1

2      3      1

3      1      0

3      2      0

3      3      0#this was 0, then all 0 for day 3
```

My problem is that, I can find any 0 on a particular day, but I don't know how to move rows up or down to change any 1 of that particular day for 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row coordinates for all the rows corresponding to a single day. Then check if any attempt did not succeed and replace the result in the table.

```
for day_number in range(3):
    coords=table.get_where_list('day==%i'%day_number)
    table_data=table.read_coordinates(coords)
    attempts_succeeded=np.all(table_data['ok'])
    table_data['ok'][:]=attempts_succeeded
    table.modify_coordinates(coords,table_data)
```

It is probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but it should work.

Comment: Hey, thanks, this makes sense, but I am not sure if it would work for me. It is my fault, I forgot to mention that, the day column means the week, so the table is huge, but the days are kind of a loop, 11122233344455666777111222333....so I will need to test the behaviour if this code after the "first week". Anyway you showed me a possible way to do this, I will work on it, THANKS.

Comment: @user2919052: ok,so the day is the weekday. what do you call huge? I would consider reading in the table piecewise (several hundred thousand to a million lines), treating the data in memory and writing it back to new file. You only need to do this operation once, if I am correct.

Comment: When I said huge, well, the table that I am using to "play" and test the scripts has 1.5milion of rows, but I believe that, in the future it can be even bigger.

Comment: 1 million rows with 3 entries (int16,int16,bool) corresponds to about 5 MB so this easily fits into memory...much easier and faster to operate on numpy arrays which you can then dump into files of whatever kind you like.